# A problem of arithmetical means and function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Assume $f(x)=\frac{2^{x+1}}{2^x+1}$,and $\{a_n\}$ is a arithmetic sequences which common difference is $1$，and $$f(a_1)+f(a_2)+\cdots+f(a_{2017})=2017$$,finde the value of : $f^2(a_{1009})-a_{1008}a_{1010}$

---

My approach:
I tried to use $\sum f(a_k)=2017$ to find $a_1$, but  I am failed to sum this series. If I set $2^{a_k}=c_k$ , then $\{c_k\}$ is a geometric series which common ratio is $2$. after some calculus, I need to sum $$\frac{1}{c_1+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{c_{2017}+1}$$  in order to find $c_1$, but I am failed.

Comment: Is {$a_n$} fixed? Otherwise take $a_1=-1013$ and then realize that $f(x)+f(-x)$ is constant, so you can find $a_{1013}$ and then you can easily find the value of expression.

Comment: You should get too $\,\displaystyle \sum_{n=-m}^m \frac 1{2^n+1}=m+\dfrac 12\,$ but I favor rather $a_1=-1008$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2017}f(a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{2017}f(a_1+i-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{2017}\left(2-\frac{2}{2^{a_1+i-1}+1}\right):=g(a_1)$$
is strictly increasing on $a_1$.

Now, as arberavdullahu comments, we have
$$f(x)+f(-x)=2$$
from which we have
$$f(a_i)+f(a_{2-2a_1-i})=2$$
where $a_j=-a_i\iff a_1+j-1=-a_1-i+1\iff j=2-2a_1-i$.

Using this, we get
$$g(-1008)=\sum_{i=1}^{1008}(f(a_i)+f(a_{2018-i}))+f(a_{1009})=2\times 1008+1=2017$$
from which we have $$a_1=-1008$$

Thus, we have
$$f^2(a_{1009})-a_{1008}a_{1010}=\left(\frac{2^{0+1}}{2^{0}+1}\right)^2-(-1)\cdot 1=\color{red}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all $1\leq f(x)<2$ for $x\geq0$. As a result, if we assume all $a_k>0$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{2017}f(a_k)>2017$, so some of $a_k<0$, **specifically $a_1<0$**.

Then $f(x)<1, \forall x<0$ and, similarly, we deduct that some of the $a_k>0$, **specifically $a_{2017}>0$**.

From the structure of the sequence, **$\exists m: a_m=0$**.

Now:
$$f(x)=\frac{2^{x+1}}{2^x+1}=\frac{2\cdot(2^x+1-1)}{2^x+1}=2-\frac{2}{2^x+1}$$

$$2017=\sum_{k=1}^{2017}f(a_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\left(2-\frac{2}{2^{a_k}+1}\right)=2\cdot2017-2\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}=\frac{2017}{2}$$
Or
$$\frac{2017}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}$$
Or
$$1008=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}$$
It's easy to see $$\frac{1}{2^{x}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{-x}+1}=\frac{1}{2^{x}+1}+\frac{2^{x}}{2^{x}+1}=1$$
**The remaining part is to show $m-1=1008$.**

**Case 1** if $m-1<1008$ then
$$1008=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}=m-1+\sum_{k=2m-1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}$$
or
$$1008-m+1=\sum_{k=2m-1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}<\sum_{k=2m-1}^{2017}1=1008-m+1$$
contradiction.

**Case 2** if $m-1>1008$ then
$$1008=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{T}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}+2017-m$$
or
$$m-1008-1=\sum_{k=1}^{T}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}>\sum_{k=1}^{T}1=T$$
where
$$T=m-(2017-m)-1=2m-2018>m-1008-1$$
contradiction.

Since $a_m=0$ and $m-1=1008$ then $a_1=-(m-1)=-1008$ with [a quick double check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(2%5E(j%2B1))%2F(2%5Ej%20%2B%201),%20j%3D-1008%20to%201008). As a result $a_{1008}=-1,a_{1009}=0,a_{1010}=1$ and from this it's easy to compute the answer $f(0)^2-(-1)\cdot 1=2$

Comment: thanks very much ,why $\exists m :  a_m=0$, if  $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, this is right. but if some $a_k$ is not a integer, I can't find $m$ : $a_m=0$.

Comment: Hmmm ... you are right, I assumed $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, let me see if I can show that if $a_n \notin \mathbb{Z}$ then the sum $\sum f(a_k)\neq 2017$

Comment: If I show that $\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}=\frac{2017}{2}$ has only one solution,then $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$,  I set $c_k = 2^{a_k}$, and $2^x$ is strictly increasing(if we have  only one solution $c_1$,then we have only one solution $a_1$).  then $\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{2^{a_k}+1}=\frac{2017}{2}\Rightarrow$ $f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{t2^{k-1}+1}-\frac{2017}{2}=0$ has only one solution $c_1$ ,because $f'(t) = -\sum \frac{2^{k-1}}{(1+t2^{k-1})^2} <0$

Comment: @Laura that's a really awesome strategy!